# How to get the SOAP request message with Java and Axis 1.4

Tags: java, logging, axis, soap-client

For the purposes of logging, I need to get the content of SOAP request and SOAP response. 
In general I have 2 alternatives:

- to extend part of Axis API (BasicHandler) and to create an
  interceptor, which will log everything for me.
- or I could to the logging "manually" i.e. using the utility of Axis
  only as a client - no extending.

For reasons the approach of the projects  points me to implementing the logging manually.
So far I managed to get the SOAP response like this:

```
    private void getSOAPasString(Call call) {

    try {
        MessageContext context = call.getMessageContext();
        SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();

        // Create transformer
        TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tf;
        tf = tff.newTransformer();


    // Get reply content
    Source sc = message.getSOAPPart().getContent();

    // Set output transformation
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    tf.transform(sc, result);

    System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But I haven't managed to get the request message - can you help me with that? Is it possible to get the Request SOAP message? How?